# Substitution of content by js

Tags: javascript, queryselector

I have a problem with JS code. Well, the text of the first link changes. The second one stays the same and I would like to change too. How to do it correctly?

HTML:

```
<h4 class="comments-title">Text1</h4>
        <a rel="nofollow" class="comment-reply-link" href="#comment-25416">reply</a>    

        <a rel="nofollow" class="comment-reply-link" href="#comment-2">reply</a>
```

JS:

```
    function podmien(klasa, tekst) {
    document.querySelector(klasa).innerHTML = tekst;
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
podmien('.comments-title', 'Com');
podmien('.comment-reply-link', 'Answer');
Document.getElementsByClassName
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tomaszpl/8s43wao5/28/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`querySelector` will only select the first element. What you need is `querySelectorAll` to select **all** elements.

```js
function podmienAll(klasa, tekst) {
  document.querySelectorAll(klasa).forEach(v => {
    v.innerHTML = tekst;
  });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  podmienAll('.comments-title', 'Com');
  podmienAll('.comment-reply-link', 'Answer');
});
```

```html
<h4 class="comments-title">Text1</h4>
<a rel="nofollow" class="comment-reply-link" href="#comment-25416">reply</a>
<a rel="nofollow" class="comment-reply-link" href="#comment-2">reply</a>
```